# Is it possible to create a Team-Recording-Bot using .Net Core? or is it only be created using .Net Framework?

Tags: .net-core, microsoft-graph-api, botframework, microsoft-graph-cloudcommunications

I am creating a bot to record team meetings. I can join team meetings. I am not able to record team meetings. I have added a compliance recording policy to it but it is not enabling the recording. Is it possible to record team meetings using .Net core? Or should I go for python language for creating a team recording bot.?

Comment: `I can join team meetings` so why not using a screen record tool to do that ?

Comment: I have to enable team meeting recording. I don't want any screen record tool.

Comment: When Ai bot joins the Team meeting at the same time it should enable team recording.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Teams recording bot [sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/tree/master/Samples/V1.0Samples/AksSamples/teams-recording-bot) on the Microsoft Graph Github repos, along with other Teams bot samples. You can use them as a starting point.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using all samples code but they are in the .net framework, but we require it to do it in.net core. I have also tried to change from the .net framework to the .net core but it is not working. Is there any way to do it in .net core? Please help us with this. Any help will be appriciated

Comment: If the packages used in the samples to implement recording are not present in .NET Core, then there won't be a standard way of doing it.

Comment: I am able to record using above code by deploying that code as it is on azure kubernetis. Please go to docs folder then deploy folder and there you will find aks. Md document to deploy the bot on azure kubernetis. Thanks