# Do BotFramework allow us to enable team recording using Ai bot

Tags: botframework

I need to record team meetings using the bot framework SDK. Is it possible? Do BotFramework has the functionality to enable team recording automatically using Ai Bot.

Answer (score 0):

No. This kind of functionality belongs more to the Teams side of things, so there is no default and automatic way to enable this. Your best bet is to use the Teams-developed samples for this functionality, as I linked in your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71920923/is-it-possible-to-create-a-team-recording-bot-using-net-core-or-is-it-only-be/71929491#71929491).